# use a cookie for a mysql query 

Tags: php, mysql

Hello how would I use a cookie in a MySQL statement. I am using this variable for a MySQL query and i don't know how to access the cookie's value in a MySQL query. I need to have the variable to be safe against sql injection attacks. Thanks any help is appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be in need of a "PHP 101" book. How to use the most basic language syntax and features are not questions you should be asking professionals on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']) . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah... `$_COOKIE` or `$_SESSION`

google `PHP cookie`

Comment: $_COOKIE["cookiename"] i already have this but the value of the cookie is stored in a mysql database and these need to match the cookie stored in the browser but how would I put this in a mysql query?

Comment: I believed you asked a different question. You should just get each cookie an id.

Comment: I'm sorry I was just wondering how I would accomplish this by putting this in a variable or to access this variable in a mysql query I didn't understand that the cookie was already a variable but what is it stored as in my script?

Comment: You should edit your questions to ask about MySQL. You need a solution which is safe against injection attacks too.

Comment: @spencer, you need to edit your question to include more information about your database tables. So we know what kind of a query you want to write.

Comment: `$_COOKIE['cookiename']` **is a variable**. What are you going on about putting it in a variable? `mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']) . "'");`

Comment: ugh.. used prep'ed statment please? >.<

Comment: oh i get it sorry about the variable thing i was confused

Comment: Thank you guys so much you fixed it also thanks for putting up with my beginner question next time i will read up on my issue much more thoroughly before asking my question here. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you should use Session instead of Cookies since it provides more security than Cookies.

Try this:

```
//some codes conection, start session, query to database, fetch row to get the result then test

   if($result){  //for example, $result = mysql_fetch_array($query)
       //set session variable here
       $_SESSION['sess_name1'] = $result['col_name'];
       $_SESSION['sess_name2'] = $result['col_name'];
       ..............................................
   }else{
       echo "Error.".mysql_error();
   }
```

You can retrieve the value of the session variable on every page by:
1. Start the session by using `session_start();` at the top of that page
2. Call for the value like `$welcome = $_SESSION['sess_name1'];`
3. Then you can use it as much as you want.
4. To unset the session, use `session_destroy();` or `$_SESSION['sess_name1'] = ''` to unset the specific session variable